# Everywhere differentiable function whose derivative is not locally integrable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

My question is all in the title: I can’t come up with an example of a function $u \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that

1. $u$ is differentiable at every $x \in \mathbb R$
2. $u’ \notin L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R)$

Any ideas?

Comment: You are looking for an example of a function which is differentiable at all points, but whose derivative is unbounded. This is a classic example of a function which is differentiable but not Lipschitz, and hence has a derivative which is unbounded. 
Define
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x \sin\left(\frac 1 x\right) & x \ne 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
As you can see, the function $f$ is differentiable at all points, but its derivative $f’$ is unbounded.

Comment: @Amirreza Hashemi You need $x^2$ for the function to be differentiable at $0$. Unbounded functions can be Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @AmirrezaHashemi The derivative of your function is locally integrable.

Comment: $x^{2}\sin (\frac 1 {x^{2}}), x \neq 0$, $0$ for $x=0$ does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine all the ideas from the comments, define $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2}) & x\not=0 \\ 0 &x=0\end{cases}$$

Then it's easy to see $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere, and whenever $x\not=0$, $$f'(x)=2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})+x^2\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})\frac{-2}{x^3}=2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})+\frac{-2\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})}{x}$$

Note that $2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ is continuous and hence locally integrable, it's sufficient to show $g(x):=\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})}{x}$ is not around $0$. It's clearly unbounded, but this is insufficient to conclude it's not locally integrable.

Indeed, in the inverval $\frac{1}{x^2}\in [2n\pi, 2n\pi + \frac{1}{3}\pi]$, we have $\frac{1}{x}\ge \sqrt{2n\pi}\gg\sqrt{n}$, and $\cos(\frac{1}{x})\ge \frac{1}{2}\gg 1$. And the length of the interval is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\pi}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\pi + \frac{1}{3}\pi}}=\frac{\pi/3}{\sqrt{2n\pi + \frac{1}{3}\pi}\cdot\sqrt{2n\pi}\cdot(\sqrt{2n\pi + \frac{1}{3}\pi}+\sqrt{2n\pi})}\gg \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

Hence $\int_0^\epsilon g^+(x)dx\gg\sum_{n=m(\epsilon)}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty$.